# Printing current code line and specific variables' names, types and dimensions

Tags: matlab, debugging, octave

To debug my Octave/MATLAB code, I want to be able to do something like:

```
A = magic(3);
b = 42;
describe(@A, @b);
```

and get output like:

```
filename.m line 3: "A" is a 3x3 matrix
filename.m line 3: "b" is a scalar of value: 42
```

For multiple variables, how can I print the:

- Calling function's file and line
- Name
- Type
- Dimensions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Overview

In this answer I list 3 subtly different versions of the function `describe`.

1. Takes any number of variables and creates an output string and displays it using `fpritnf`
2. Takes any number of variables and creates an output **cell array** and displays it using `disp`
3. Takes any number of variable **names** and creates an output string as in 1. This has the advantage of being able to deal with indexing like `describe('myvar{1}')`.

---

#### Main functionality description and version 1.

You can use various standard functions to get the info you want:

- `varargin` to accept variable number of input variables
- `dbstack` to get the file name / current line
- `inputname` to get the names of inputs as they are passed into `describe`
- `fprintf` to display with new line characters
- `varargout` to optionally return or display the result

So create your `describe` function like so:

```
function varargout = describe(varargin)
    % varargin used to accomodate variable number of inputs
    % By default, at least get functions stack (even if no variables are passed in)
    st = dbstack;
    % Convert cell output to string (excluding describe.m itself)
    outstring = '';
    % Loop backwards for more logical order (most recent last)
    for ii = size(st, 1):-1:2
        % new line character at end only works with fprintf, not disp
        outstring = [outstring, st(ii).file, ' > ', st(ii).name, ...
                     ', line ', num2str(st(ii).line), '\n'];
    end
    % Loop over variables and get info
    for n = 1:nargin
        % Use inputname to get name of input variables
        outstring = [outstring, '"', inputname(n), '" is a ', ...
                     class(varargin{n}), ' of size ', mat2str(size(varargin{n})), '\n'];
    end
    % If output variable is requested then assign to output variable
    % If not, just display output string to command window 
    if nargout 
        varargout{1} = outstring;
    else
        fprintf(outstring)
    end
end
```

The only tweaking required here really is formatting, all of your requested functionality is here and hopefully enough flexibility is built in to handle your needs.

---

**Example output**:

```
% In myMainFunction.m, in the subfunction mySubFunction
% Could store output using 'd = describe(A,B);' and use 'fprintf' later 
describe(A, B);
% In the command window
myMainFunction.m > myMainFunction, line 3
myMainFunction.m > mySubFunction, line 39
"A" is a double of size [1 3]
"B" is a double of size [1 5 9 7]
```

---

Tested in Matlab R2015b, all functions listed above existed since before R2006a according to documentation so I assume it's likely that they have Octave equivalents.

---

#### Version 2.

**Cell instead of string with line separators.**

This has a less pretty output but is also perhaps a less clunky method, assigning the strings to a cell array rather than having to rely on `fprintf` for new lines. It can be done easily using the following (uncommented for brevity) version.

```
function varargout = describe(varargin)
    st = dbstack; outcell = {};
    for ii = size(st, 1):-1:2
        outcell{end+1} = [st(ii).file, ' > ', st(ii).name, ', line ', num2str(st(ii).line)];
    end
    for n = 1:nargin
        outcell{end+1} = ['"', inputname(n), '" is a ',  class(varargin{n}), ' of size [', size(varargin{n}), ']'];
    end
    outcell = outcell.'; % Transpose to make it a column cell array
    disp(outcell)
end
```

---

#### Version 3.

**Passing variable *names* as strings, so things like `'myvar(1)'` are displayed.**

This uses `evalin` to evaluate the variables in the `caller` workspace (where `describe` was called from). NOTE: This could be more memory intensive as you are recreating the variables in this `describe` function to get their attributes.

```
function varargout = describe(varargin)
    % varargin used to accomodate variable number of input names
    st = dbstack;
    outstring = '';
    for ii = size(st, 1):-1:2
        outstring = [outstring, st(ii).file, ' > ', st(ii).name, ', line ', num2str(st(ii).line), '\n'];
    end
    % Loop over variables and get info
    for n = 1:nargin
        % Variables are passed by name, so check if they exist
        try v = evalin('caller', varargin{n});
            outstring = [outstring, '"', varargin{n}, '" is a ', class(v), ' of size ', mat2str(size(v)), '\n'];   
        catch
            outstring = [outstring, 'Variable "', varargin{n}, '" not found!\n'];
        end
    end
    fprintf(outstring)
end
```

Example use:

```
% This can be used with indexed variables too. MUST PASS STRINGS!
describe('C{1}', 'B(1:2, :)')
% In the command window
myMainFunction.m > myMainFunction, line 3
myMainFunction.m > mySubFunction, line 39
"C{1}" is a double of size [1 3]
"B(1:2, :)" is a double of size [2 5]

% Because you're passing strings, you can use command syntax if you want
% Gives same result but don't have to pass strings 
% as that's how inputs are interpreted anyway for command syntax.
describe C{1} B(1:2, :)
```

Comment: +1. However, I would be cautious of using `inputname` when one isn't aware of the input type as it fails for 'non-simple' inputs (I have been bitten by this myself). I would probably advise passing the variable name as a string instead, and then use `evalin` inside the function. This has the added benefit that you can then use "command syntax" as well, i.e. `describe A b`.

Comment: Thanks for the comment @Tasos, I hadn't used `inputname` before so useful to know, could alternatively use a simple `try`/`catch` if you're aware of this potential issue. @Tom I accidentally rejected your edit when I made my own, but I see no advantage to using `[]` over `""` or using `mat2str` in place of manual bracketting in my answer, feel free to make this edit in your own implementation :)

Comment: I use [`typeinfo`](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/v4.0.3/Data-Types.html) instead of `class` to get `matrix` instead of `double` - consider updating?

Also, I just hit an example of @TasosPapastylianou's issue: `describe(activation{3});` gives `"" is a matrix of size [5000 10]`.

Is there a trick to using variable argument lists and `evalin`?

Comment: What do you expect to be in the name field, 'activation{3}'? I see `typeinfo` is Octave only, so I'll leave my answer as-is having noted I tested on MATLAB, you can use typeinfo if you wish and leave that comment for others to see!

Comment: Can you add a `;` after `try v = evalin('caller', varargin{n})` to suppress printing the value of temporary variable `v`?

Comment: Ah that must be another Octave/MATLAB quirk, as MATLAB surpresses the output of `v` anyway, but yes you can add a semi-colon at the end of that line :)

Comment: Use `if isscalar(v)` with `num2str(v)` to print out the value of scalars as per OP's example.

Answer (score 1):

I use something similar myself. Here's mine:

```
function describe(A)
  fprintf('       Class : %s\n',class(A));
  fprintf('  Num. Elems : %s\n',num2str(numel(A)));  
  fprintf('        Size : %s\n',num2str(size(A)));
  fprintf('   Total Min : %s\n',num2str(min (A(:))));
  fprintf('   Total Max : %s\n',num2str(max (A(:))));  
  fprintf('   Total Sum : %s\n',num2str(sum (A(:))));
  fprintf('  Total Mean : %s\n',num2str(mean(A(:))));
  fprintf('Total St.Dev : %s\n',num2str(std (A(:), 1)));
  fprintf(' Unique vals : %s\n',num2str(length(unique(A))));  
end
```

**Edit:** I'm aware this isn't a literal answer to what you ask, but I use this all the time and thought it might be useful to share. :)

---

<sub>PS. Having said that, it has never occurred to me that I might ever want to use such a function in a non-interactive way: if I need to inspect variables in this manner, I just put a breakpoint (or `keyboard` instruction) in the code and then inspect stuff in the terminal at the point where it's most relevant, so reporting a filename and a linenumber manually has never occurred to me! What is your use-case that you need to perform non-interactive debugging like this? If it's for post-mortem "testing" purposes, you really should be writing proper tests and sanity checks instead anyway!</sub>

<sub>Also, this is only for single variables, but I find that preferable; it's an extremely simple one-liner loop if you wanted more anyway.</sub>

Comment: This doesn't do 2 of the 4 things the OP asked for? Namely the calling line and file, and the name of the variable... See my answer for both and a variable number of inputs, maybe helpful for you if you already use this function :)

Comment: I suppose it's not a literal answer then. I just recognised this as something similar to what I have and in the same spirit, so I thought I'd share :)   (I have upvoted your answer)

Comment: Cheers Tasos, maybe the OP will find some of your additional properties useful

Comment: @Wolfie I do have to say, this is something I use more when I'm fiddling in the terminal trying to make sense of my workspace. I never thought of it as something that one would want to use non-interactively. Interesting :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `size` to have the size of your variable, for the type use `class` and for the name use `inputname`.
For example:

```
function describe(a)
  s = size(a); % Return the size of a
  t = class(a); % Return the type of a
  name = inputname(1); % Return the name of a

  printf(['filename.m line 3: ''''' name ''''' size:' s(1) 'x' s(2) ' and type: ' t]);
end
```

I don't know how to use the name of file and the line, and if you want another way to display this you can can use if condition to seperate scalar from vector from matrix.

Comment: Doesn't allow for more than 2 dimensions, eg: `size(cell(2,3,4))`.

Comment: Like i said, if you want a better function than this, you can code it, I give you  the key now you can use it. And for more than 2 dimensions you can do

    `s = size(a);
    size_string = [num2str(s(1))];
    for i = 2:size(s)
      size_string = [size_string ['x' s(i)] ];
    end`